# Xcode : How To Set App To Be iPhone Only?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

We have set the following app settings to be iPhone only, but in the App Store the app is listed as iPhone/iPad compatible.

As you can see in the following image, the device family is set to be just iPhones:

[image]

Here is App: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/carrom-pro/id525961441?mt=8.

Is there anything wrong with these settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All iPhone applications can be run on the iPad as well, just not "fullscreen" (see image below). Applications can be designed for iPhone and iPad separately, or a universal app, which contains the resources for both iPhone and iPad (interfaces, device handling, etc.).

[image]

The user will notice a gray container around an application that is designed for iPhone. Universal apps will automatically choose the correct interface for the device.

In the iTunes Store, applications with a blue plus symbol beside the price are Universal applications:

[image]

Comment: yes in 2x mode, then no difference for iPhone only device settings and Universal device settings? How end user can identify its really iPad app with universal settings?

Comment: you mean for universal app that "+This app is designed for...dialog comes?" or client need to set in developer account?

Comment: So yours was developed for iPhone, but it can be run on iPad like the image above.

Answer (score 14):

Setting the deployment Devices to "Iphone" wont restrict it to iphone only.

The only way to do it is to add some **Required Device capabilities** which iPad doesn't have. e.g., If you add **telephony** or **sms** to the **Required Device capabilities** in Info.plist of the app, apple will automatically make the app available only for iPhone.

For more device capabilities, refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: Device capabilities :- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Comment: Can I simply activate the HealthKit capability without using it?

Comment: +1. I had wondered how Apple had created apps that are really-iPhone-only, like Calculator.app, and it just seemed like there should be build solution, rather than Apple simply changing distro they loaded in device MFG. This seems like approach that could do this.

Answer (score 5):

Keep **UIDeviceFamily** property to **1** (for iPhone) in app plist file and also change the **Targeted Device Family** in **Build settings** to **1** (for iPhone). Keep **2** in the both cases if you want to support iPad only. These are tested in XCode 8.

Answer (score 1):

All iphone games can run in iPad. Therefore iTunes is writing iPhone/iPad. 
For search a iPad only games, user will search in iPad tab in iTunes where no any iPhone games, therefore don't worry about this.
Universal device and iPhone only settings for iTunes detecting a apps for sort. And on some case for developers.