# Exclude iPad support from existing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have found multiple exiting questions on this but have different scenario's

My app have separate view for iPhone and iPad but now my client want to remove iPad support for next 1year, I am thinking about the consequences

1) If I remove deployment target from Universal to iPhone? My app still run on iPad when upload to apple store and if run it will display 2x of iPhone screen or my iPad specific views?
2) Existing app in apple store is universal if i change it to iPhone only does apple have some restriction on that too while uploading new binary?

Comment: 1st question, YES, 2nd question NO.

Comment: 1st question!! if I upload it and someone try to run on iPad it will shows iPad's view or iPhone in 2x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it is to add some Required Device capabilities which iPad doesn't have. e.g., If you add telephony or sms to the Required Device capabilities in Info.plist of the app, apple will automatically make the app available only for iPhone. As suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767346/xcode-how-to-set-app-to-be-iphone-only).

Comment: Does apple reject app when I add Required Device capabilities key in plist?