# iPhone only app rejected for not running on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store, appstore-approval

I received the following from Apple. I tried fixing the constraints for just iPad but I can get the scroll bar to come on top. How would I fix this? It is an iPhone only app. Thanks

[image: Image of my app on the iPad]

From Apple
2. 4 PERFORMANCE: HARDWARE COMPATIBILITY
Performance - 2.4.1

We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.2. Specifically, we were unable to register as the sign-up option was behind the amount section.

We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to ensure it runs and displays properly at iPhone resolution on iPad.

Resources

For information on iOS device screen sizes and resolutions, please see the iOS Human Interface Guidelines as well as the Points versus Pixels in the View Programming Guide for iOS.

Additional Information

If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.

If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
- complete details of your rejection issue(s)
- screenshots
- steps to reproduce the issue(s)
- symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode : How To Set App To Be iPhone Only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767346/xcode-how-to-set-app-to-be-iphone-only)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. A comment was here earlier about setting things to iPhone only - and while it's gone, I'm not seeing that it was. Either way, this was **rejected** where this possible dup flag is looking at something that wasn't.

Comment: Please note that settings an app as `iPhone only` does not prohibit iPad users from downloading it. All this means is that the app is only allowed to run with iPhone display defaults. An iPad user is still able to download and install your app. They simply need to check the preference to also display "iPhone only" apps in their App Store search results. When running the app on their iPad, they will view it at "iPhone resolution". So in order to pass the App Store review cycle, iPad hardware must be supported even if iPad display/resolution is not directly supported.

Comment: @Michael_Fourre, are you saying that Apple would reject this app for some reason? I flagged the potential duplicate comment precisely because nothing there state this is a cause for rejection, which the OP is clearly asking about.

Comment: you need to provide more details on your constraints, but it seems you haven't tested on small screen phones since this what happens when you run an iPhone app on an iPad; it runs at the lowest iPhone resolution

Comment: @menan did you figure this out? I just got rejected for the same reason.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an issue with supported devices - even if the iOS app is for iPhone only, it has to run on iPhone resolution on an iPad. This is the same sizing (or very, very close) as running on a iPhone 4 simulator, based on the screenshots.

Fix the constraints for iPhone 4 and it will be approved.

Comment: Good tip Thanks. But with Xcode 9 the list of simulators stops at iPhone 5s :(

Comment: Try it on some/all of the iPad simulators. Ideally the app should be flexible enough to work on any of the simulator options, or Apple may reject.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with my app which had the Deployment Info set to iPhone. Did they attach a screenshot with their response?

The issue with mine was that the constraints weren't set up properly. On smaller screen sizes (which the 1x setting on the iPad shows) my buttons were pushed together.

Check out your build on the simulator using an iPhone 5.

Comment: So it's an "responsive" issue on small screen like iPhone 5 ? Why are they referring to iPad then ? :S (I have actually the same issue)

Comment: Hey @Zetura - iPad users can download apps even if the deployment info states just iPhone. What the iPad does is show it on the screen, but still the size as if it was on an iphone, so there ends up being a lot of empty black space around the phone. If a user wants it to be bigger, they can click a 2x button on the button right of the iPad. If you run your app in the simulator with iPad Air, you'll see what I mean. Basically, the iPad Air shows the same size screen that you would see on an iPhone 5, so you can check if your app works for the smallest screen size using either.

Comment: Yes, I know that ;) It's just that my app is still rejected, and everything seems fine on the screenshot that Apple sent to me. The only thing, is that the app is showing in scale 2x on iPad by default, and I need to click on 1x in the corner to have the iPhone resolution. I found that weird and I hope it's not why they are rejecting...

Comment: That's really weird @Zetura :( Mine just got approved after I made some changes and it also shows in scale 2x by default, so I think that's alright. Do you have buttons in your app/could the height of the buttons be changing? I've seen an error before where the constraints break, the buttons change heigh to be 1, but the label of the button still makes it look normal size. It looks the same, but users can't actually click the button because it's only 1 pixel high

Comment: No, everything is working. I tried on iPhone 4, iPhone 5 (simulator and real), iPad retina (simulator and real), iPad Air,... And I have different versions of the app for different countries, and some are validated and some rejected. I will just try to republish the app and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my app.

My application was intended for iPhone and not for iPad, but the apple review team told me this:

> It would be appropriate to revise your app to ensure that it runs on
>   iPad at iPhone resolution.

My solution:

Optimize the user interface for iPhone 4

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Supported minimum iOS version is not relevant! I got rejection with iPad (1X) screenshot. App supports min version 10!

<strike>The problem is your app supports "minimum iOS version=9". it means your app must support 1x (not only2x or 3x) . Probably Apple itc review team tests the apps on ipad mini with 1x screen for iphone 4 device testing.</strike>

just optimize UI for 1x (iphone 4/4s)

Answer (score 0):

I had also same issues throw me by apple. i search and got it solution to give support iPhone4 . this will resolved the issues.

Update your view constraint and give support to iphone4 or Run the app in the ipad and give support.

Answer (score 0):

Simple remove suffix _iphone.storyboard or _ipad.storyboard, just may use Main.storyboard will fix this appstore issue