# Iphone resolution on ipad howto using codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I've submitted a CN1 generated app to apple's app store and got an error:

---

Binary Rejected

### Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance - Hardware Compatibility We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad.

I was wondering if there's a build hint I cant set to make the app show a narrow interface on an ipad? many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably similar to this: [iPhone only app rejected for not running on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730125/iphone-only-app-rejected-for-not-running-on-ipad)

You can constrain the app to be iPhone only in the Codename One Settings UI under the iOS settings section.